# Airplay icon disappears after mac wakes up from sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, appletv, airplay

I have found that when my mac wakes up from sleep, sometimes there is no airplay icon. The  only way I can fix this is by doing a recycle of my MacBook Air. I was wondering if there was any other way to have the airplay icon back on my MBA without having to restart it. Perhaps there is a command I can type on the Terminal. Anyone has a clue?

(FYI - Restarting the AppleTV does not solve the issue so I believe its a Mountain Lion part of things.)

Comment: What does "a recycle" of your Air involve?

Comment: Shutdown and restart

Answer (score 1):

Try cycling your MBA's Wi-Fi? I would expect powering your machine's antenna down and then back up would re-engage the Airplay internals.

Comment: @ Ben Mosher - Will try and let you know but but my router, dlink DIR-651 takes much more time to restart (and disconnects all other machines and devices while doing so) than my MBA so I would not really want to do it...

Comment: Sorry, meant your MBA. Edited the answer for clarification.